# How element.findElement() method in selenium works [not driver.findElement()]

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I do below code, code works perfectly fine

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("String1"));
element.findElement(By.xpath("String2"));
```

But when we do as below

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("String1"));
element.convertStringToXpath("String2");

// Method written in some other class
public WebElement convertStringToXpath(String xpath) {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    }
```

I am getting Error as below
The method convertStringToXpath(String) is undefined for the type WebElement

Can anyone explain the difference between the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets see whats happening in both of your code blocks :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("String1"));
element.findElement(By.xpath("String2");
```

In  this code block, we have defined an `WebElement` by the name **`element`** and have assigned the node identified by `(By.xpath("String1"))` within the scope of the entire **`DOM Tree`** accessible to the **`WebDriver`** instance i.e. `driver`. Next we are using the reference of this `WebElement` i.e. **`element`** to identify another node identified by `(By.xpath("String2"))` within the `scope` of **`element`**.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("String1"));
element.convertStringToXpath("String2");

// Method written in some other class
public WebElement convertStringToXpath(String xpath) {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    }
```

In this block as well, we have defined an `WebElement` by the name **`element`** and have assigned the node identified by `(By.xpath("String1"))` within the scope of the entire **`DOM Tree`** accessible to the **`WebDriver`** instance i.e. `driver`. Next you are trying to invoke a custom method **`convertStringToXpath()`** through the **`element`**. But **`element`** is of type **`WebElement`**. **`convertStringToXpath()`** is a customized method and not defined in the **`WebElement`** interface. Hence you see the error **The method convertStringToXpath(String) is undefined for the type WebElement**

Answer (score 1):

`convertStringToXpath` is a method you wrote, its not part of the `WebElement` API so you can't use it like that. This will work

```
WebElement element = someOtherClassInstance.convertStringToXpath("String2");
```